# How do I debug why a node is evaluated?

Tags: tensorflow

In Tensorflow, Placeholders must only be fed if the goal depends on it:

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [], "x")
y = 2 * x1
y = tf.Print(y, ["Computed y"])
z = 2 * y

# Error: should feed "x"
z.eval()

# OK, because y is not actually computed
z.eval({y: 1})
```

Now, in my more complex graph, I have the problem that I get an error that some placeholders are not fed, but I think that they shouldn't be needed, by the same mechanism as illustrated above.

How can I debug this? The error message only states which placeholder is needed, but not why. It would be helpful to get the path from the placeholder to the goal.

How can I get this information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the graph is not huge, you could just do backward graph search from target node

ie,

```
def find(start, target):
    """Returns path to parent from given start node"""
    if start == target:
        return [target]
    for parent in start.op.inputs:
        found_path = find(parent, target)
        if found_path:
            return [start]+found_path
    return []
```

To use it

```
tf.reset_default_graph()
a1 = tf.ones(())
b1 = tf.ones(())
a2 = 2*a1
b2 = 2*b1
a3 = 2*a2
b3 = 2*b2
d4 = b3+a3
find(d4, a1)
```

Should return

```
[<tf.Tensor 'add:0' shape=() dtype=float32>,
 <tf.Tensor 'mul_2:0' shape=() dtype=float32>,
 <tf.Tensor 'mul:0' shape=() dtype=float32>,
 <tf.Tensor 'ones:0' shape=() dtype=float32>]
```

If the graph is large, you can speed it up by restricting the search to ops between them

```
import tensorflow.contrib.graph_editor as ge
ops_between = ge.get_walks_intersection_ops(source, target)
```

[ge.get_walks_intersection_ops doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/contrib.graph_editor/module_select#get_walks_intersection_ops)

Comment: Nice, thanks! Would be good if TF would put this information in the error message. Or perhaps provide an `AssertNotEvaluated` identity Op that outputs the path if violated.